# Does Plesk 9 (CentOS) do a MySQL database dump of all databases each day?

Tags: centos5, database-backup

Anybody know? At the moment I've been looking into setting up something running via CRON to do this but if Plesk already does it 'behind the scenes' then I don't want to add unnecessary tasks to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There aren't any automatic backup jobs in plesk. 
I use Plesk 10.4. I have also used Plesk 9.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't until you configure periodic backup for that. It may be preconfigured by your hosting provider as well - checkout "Scheduled Backup Settings" in "Backup manager".